# How to solve circular reference between two tables?

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, circular-dependency, database-normalization, circular-reference

Pretty easy example:

A **Company** can have N **Locations**, and one of these **Locations** is the Main Location. Can we solve this problem with MySQL foreign keys?

Our current approach is to have a pointer to Company in each Location (company_id) and a pointer to Location in Company (main_location_id).

Assuming we don't allow null references, this approach is obviously wrong because it forbids creation: You cannot create a company because it has no main_location_id and you cannot create a Location because if has no company_id. Transactions do not help given that validations are still run in each step of the transaction.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

#### edit 1

Some people proposed to use a flag with a unique index in Location or in an intermediate table in order to solve the issue. We have already considered it but it has one main issue: It adds overhead since adding a new main location would require traversing all other locations to set their flags to false.

#### edit 2

Our preferred solution (in an ideal world) would be to check validations at the end of a transaction, and not in every step. This can be done by disabling foreign key checks, as it has been proposed in the comments, but this is of course a suboptimal solution.

#### Conclusion:

There is no way to do it with MySQL without relaxing one of the constraints. We'll use a before insert check in company to check location reference is not null.

Nevertheless, I'm still intrigued why MySQL does not allow to pass validations at the end of the transaction, instead of doing it in every step.

Comment: Can locations be shared by many companies?

Comment: Simply add a field indicating the location is a main. Or a extra table where you can add more location details like visit location or postbox stuff like that

Comment: Why aren't you allowing `null`? It solves your problem immediately. It's literally THE thing you need to implement in order to avoid adding additional tables. Nullable values for FKs exist for purposes such as yours. Use the right tool.

Comment: skelwa: nope, locations are not shared between companies.

Comment: Raymond: See my comment in the response bellow. Doing it with flags adds extra overhead we do not like and the data model would still allow for all flags to be set to false (no main location).

Comment: N.B: allowing null foreign keys would result in the possibility of having companies without main location. We do not want to allow that.

Comment: Looks like you've backed yourself into a corner there. If you don't relax one of your restrictions you can't really do this.

Comment: Is there really no other solution than relaxing restrictions? It seems such a common issue to us. The problem would be solved if validations were run at the end of the transaction, and not during each step of the transaction. It makes logical sense to me but I do not know if this is possible.

Comment: You can  `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`  but then you are responsible for doing the checks manually and it just is an error waiting to happen if you are not careful.

Comment: Yep, definitely not something I would want to do.

Comment: Allowing null foreign keys allows the inserts. It's absolutely trivial to create a trigger `before insert` on your companies table and raise an `SQLSTATE` if location is null. You're overthinking a super simple problem and avoiding the only valid solution - allowing nullable fk's.

Comment: Yep. I guess there's no other way with MySQL. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

You must have three tables.

The first, your `Company` table where you have scalar informations about your company (as name, fiscal code and so on)

The second, a table with `Location` without link to your company. In this table, i.e., you have rows as:

- Trafalgar Square
- Umberto Street

and so on

The third, a middle table, `CompanyLocation`,  where you have a double foreign key, companyId and locationId, and a third column represented by a flag (isPrimary)

That's all

Comment: I'm not convinced this is correct. In this instance the data model does not enforce the existence of a main location so you could eventually end up with a Company and Location and no MainLocation (the third table).

Comment: you can add a check constraint in the third table about isPrimary field (must one and only one for a company),so when yu add the first row for a company in that table, it must be isPrimary = true

Comment: I see. This is similar to another approach we already tried: having a isPrimary key in the location with a unique index per company. You are proposing the same but moving this flag to a third intermediate table. I do not see the benefit of having that intermediate table and we don't want to do this because it adds overhead: every time time you add a new main location you have to check all locations in order to set their isPrimary flag to false.

Comment: MySQL only parse CHECK statements it doesnt really use it @JoeTaras its in de manual